# Do I need the extensions.csproj file in my Python Azure durable function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

There is an `extensions.csproj` file in a function app I'm trying to clean up. This function app has durable functions and uses Python. Doing some research into it... See [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Clinux%2Cpython%2Cportal%2Cbash#register-extensions)

> Functions triggers and bindings are implemented as .NET extension (NuGet) packages ([cite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Clinux%2Cpython%2Cportal%2Cbash#register-extensions:%7E:text=Functions%20triggers%20and%20bindings%20are%20implemented%20as%20.NET%20extension%20(NuGet)%20packages))

The function app is utilizing the extension bundles with `host.json`, but now the question comes down to the verbage of the docs seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4%2Clinux%2Cpython%2Cportal%2Cbash#register-extensions)

> Extension bundles also removes the requirement of installing the .NET SDK and **having to deal with** the extensions.csproj file.

Does "having to deal with" mean the function app doesn't need the file at all and I can just delete it *or* does it mean that it still needs to be there, but I don't have to mess with it?

My intuition tells me I don't need the file at all due to the name of the file including "cs" which probably stands for C#, but I'm just trying to confirm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Simple terms,

Dot Net Azure Function Projects (Class Library type) uses NuGet Package Manager or Commands to install the required packages for the Function Running.

Other than .NET, Non-.NET Azure Function Projects (such as Python) and C# Script which will created from the Azure Function App Portal Menu - these projects require the Extension Bundle package that contains these [packages](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-extension-bundles/blob/v4.x/src/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle/extensions.json) for the Function App Running.

If you install the existing packages from the Extension Bundle, you will get the following error message as shown in below:
[image]

In the above MS Doc of `extensions.json`, each package of Extension Bundle contains major version that supports so no need to install explicitly.

If the specific package with specific version which is not in extension bundle, then you can install explicitly using Azure Functions Core Tools Commands.
In this process, `.csproj` file is added that contains the required packages for the project as specified in this MS Doc Extensions Installing Ways [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=v4,windows,csharp,portal,bash#install-extensions) & [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#manually-install-extensions).

`.csproj` file is not required if you don't install the Function Core tools related packages are not installed explicitly. You can use the extensions bundle in `host.json` file to install the extensions of triggers or bindings supported in Azure Functions versions v3, v4 according to the requirements.

Comment: Thank you, that was helpful. One clarifying matter would be that extension bundles are also supported in version 2 of Azure Functions runtime as stated [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#:~:text=Starting%20with%20Azure%20Functions%20version%202.x)